# Customizable wordpress shortcode is partially working but

Tags: wordpress

I am having a strange issue, i am trying to build a shortcode that works like that:

- If the user paste it in wordpress it returns default values (this isn't working)

  [cta type="test"]
- If the user paste it but edit some values it returns that values (this is working)

  [cta type="test" title="it works"]

This is the code i am tryin to work on:

```
    function cta($atts) {
  $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
    'type' => '',
    'title' => '',
    'subtitle' => '',
    'url' => '',
  ), $atts,
        'cta' );

  switch( $atts[ 'type' ] ) {
    case 'test':
      $title = 'title test default';
      $subtitle = 'default text';
      $url = 'https://www.example.com/';
      break;
  }

return '
<div class="cta-title">' . $atts['title'] . '</div>
<div class="cta-subtitle">' . $atts['subtitle'] . '</div>
';
    return;
;}
add_shortcode('cta', 'cta');
```

Can someone point me in the right direction? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if user input some value. If not serve default value.

```
function cta($atts)
{
    $atts = shortcode_atts(array(
        'type' => '',
        'title' => '',
        'subtitle' => '',
        'url' => '',
    ), $atts, 'cta');

    switch ($atts['type']) {
        case 'test':
            $title = (isset($atts['title']) && !empty($atts['title'])) ? $atts['title'] : 'title default';
            $subtitle = (isset($atts['subtitle']) && !empty($atts['subtitle'])) ? $atts['subtitle'] : 'subtitle default';
            $url = 'https://www.example.com/';
            break;
    }

    $output = '<div class="cta-title">' . $title . '</div>';
    $output .= '<div class="cta-subtitle">' . $subtitle . '</div>';

    return $output;
}

add_shortcode('cta', 'cta');
```